# "it is that, which isn't this" versus "it is that, not this"

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, parenthesis

"It is a special thing, not like anything else".

Is the above sentence in the form of and does mean:

1. "It is a special thing; [it is] not like anything else. Ellipsis
2. "It is a special thing [that is] not like anything else. Reduced relative clause
3. "It is a special thing, (not like anything else). Parenthetical expression.
4. "It is a special thing, (which is) not like anything else.

Comment: In this case it's like adding more description to it, so it's like "it's a special thing, and it's not like anything else". I'm not really sure which of these it's equivalent to.

Comment: All four mean the same as the original sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that 1,2 and 4 all capture the essence of what the original sentence means but are not nearly as idiomatic.

A semicolon usually joins closely connected ideas. It can act as a coordinating conjunction. Therefore, the two statements in the original sentence are closely related (they are both about the same "thing"), but they are neither dependant nor do they mean the same. The "thing" referred to is both special **and** not like anything else.

Something that is "not like anything else" would normally be described as "*unique*". That does not mean the same as "special". Something can be special, but not entirely unique. "Special" can mean that something is either *rare* or perhaps just different from comparable things due to one particular attribute.

For that reason, your third option is not really correct - the parenthetical statement sounds like it is defining the first, but that would not be correct - "special" does not specifically mean "not like anything else".

The original reads to me as if the writer means that the thing is special, perhaps meaning rare or valued highly, and then qualifying *why* they consider it special - that it is either unique, or has a unique quality.

Comment: I think the last question really hits it on the nose, great answer.